# What are the requirments to installing Xen?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, vps

Do I need a base OS to install Xen or can I just install Xen as the core OS?

I read that some people have tried installing Xen over Ubuntu but it didn't really work.

So if I had to install an OS like CentOS as the base and install Xen within it, what are the terminal commands to install it? And how do I install other OSes as VPS when Xen is ready?(because Xen really lacks tutorials online)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Xen might not be your only or best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Do I need a base OS to install Xen or can I just install Xen as the core OS?**

Before you can install Xen, you must first install an operating system such as RedHat/Centos,  Ubuntu, BSD, Solaris, or Windows in the normal way.

> **I read that some people have tried installing Xen over Ubuntu but it didn't really work.**

I've read people's accounts of having installed Xen on Ubuntu, so I believe it can be done without excessive difficulty.

> **to install an OS like CentOS as the base and install Xen within it, what are the terminal commands to install it?**

To install Xen:

```
yum install kernel-xen xen
```

See http://www.howtoforge.com/centos_5.0_xen for getting the machine to boot Xen

You should note that CentOS' upstream source (RedHat) have dropped Xen and support KVM.

To install KVM and then install some management tools for it:

```
yum install kvm
yum install virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python python-virtinst libvirt-client
```

---

> **how do I install other OSes as VPS**

With KVM, you can run a command like

```
virt-install \
   --name=guest1-rhel5-64 \
   --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/guest1-rhel5-64,size=8 \
   --nonsparse --vnc \
   --vcpus=2 --ram=2048 \
   --location=http://example1.com/installation_tree/RHEL5.6-Server-x86_64/os \
   --network bridge=br0 \
   --os-type=linux \
   --os-variant=rhel5.4
```

(see the man page for installing from CD or from an ISO image created using `dd`)

Or you can run the GUI tool `virt_manager` and follow the wizard for "creating a new virtual system".

---

#### Virtualisation

See the comments for a discussion of various Virtualisation systems. With respect to the first part of the above question, I think of them as falling into three groups:

- Hypervisors which you can install without first having installed a conventional operating system. For example VMWare ESXi
- Hypervisors which are installed after you have installed a conventional operating system but which (to some extent) replace the normal operating system kernel. When you boot the computer, it boots the hypervisor first. For example Xen (and Hyper V if I understand correctly)
- Hypervisors which are added to an operating system as a module. These essentially extend the existing kernel using existing published kernel facilities rather than replacing (key parts of) the kernel. For example KVM.

The above is a simplification and reflects my own opinion and limited understanding. Virtualisation is a complicated subject (viz Paravirtualisation, Intel VD-x, AMD V, ...) - consult Wikipedia, Google and other sources for a better understanding of Virtualisation.

Comment: so xen cant be the base i need to install something like centos?

Comment: The only bare-metal hypervisor I know of is VMware ESXi (which I believe is currently free for personal use).

Comment: It is free, but the downside of ESXi is that you won't have console access to an operating system, only to the fairly basic ESXi management interface. If you want to access a running VM, you'll need to do it remotely.

Comment: Technically, Xen is a baremetal hypervisor.  Just because you need to install it through a guest OS has no baring on whether it is baremetal or not.  Xen, just like ESX, run at below Ring 0, technically making it a baremetal visor.

Comment: @surfasb: Thanks for the clarification. So Sarmen B could install Centos, use that as a method to install Xen, and run Centos as a guest OS (without reinstalling Centos as a guest explicitly?). Other guests would have to be installed (or imaged P2V).

Comment: Technically, the Centos OS becomes Xen.  Xen server will recompile the kernel and that's how Xen server becomes a Type 1(Bare metal) visor.  Unlike ESX, it cannot function without this host OS, called Dom 0. Xen server takes control of the host OS's drivers.  ESX comes with it own drivers, thus it doesn't need a host OS. Well, that's oversimplifying it because technically, ESX is just a recompiled Linux kernel also, but no console.  The advantage of Xen server is the availability of drivers.  ESX runs on a much smaller available set of hardware.

Comment: Hyper V works in the same way as Xen. It keeps you from having to write a whole nother set of drivers.  So you can't really get rid of the Host OS, unless you want a kernel with no hardware drivers.  But after the host OS is installed, all the visors work like any other virtual machine software.  So yes, Xen (or Centos + Xen) can run on its own.

Comment: @surfasb: Thanks, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: You can place ESX and KVM together.  Note, KVM is just an OS that you install and it provides virtualization with its own drivers.  ESX is an OS that you install and it provides virtualization with its own drivers. Hyper V and Xen use the Parent Partition/ Dom 0 drivers to interface with the hardware.  Child Partitions send their I/O calls along a virtual bus. The I/O calls are then handled by those drivers that are a part of the Parent Partition/Dom 0. In a sense, the Parent/Dom 0 kernel **is** the visor.

Comment: Paravirtualization is in contrast to full virtualization. Full virtualization is the traditional meaning: Guest OS is running on a fully isolated VM.  ParaV is when the Guest OS is aware of the visor.  When it is aware(Xen jargon) or enlightened(HyperV) or transparent (VMware), the Guest kernel is loaded with special drivers to sync(integrations features) with the visor, thus boosting performance. Child VMs can also share mapped memory, etc etc. Man, we need to get the SF folks on this. They'll turn this into a book.